# how do I join two tables with different fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have two tables that I would like to join on the following fields

Table A

```
ID
2345
2346
2347
```

TableB

```
BarecodeID
*2345U12*
*2346P1*
*2346P2*
*2346P3*
*2347Z1*
*2347Z2*
```

TableB.BarCodeID was generated from TableA.ID earlier in front-end access by concatenating

```
TableB.BarcodeID = '*' & TableA.ID & 'Z' & x & '*'
```

so in order to join I would like to trim, extract, etc!!!!! off the "*" from the ends and trim off the Characters and numbers that follow (e.g U12, P1, P2, etc).

Please advise on best practice to join two table of similar fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something `LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableB.BarecodeID LIKE CONCAT('*', TableA.ID, '[A-Z]%')
```

This assumes that the numbers are always followed by a character. So `2345` will match `*2345WHATEVER` but not `*23456WHATEVER`.